# While doing a double masters, is my Bachelor's GPA being looked or my masters?

Tags: graduate-school, masters

Say I do a masters in Nepal in data science but want to pursue masters in cybersecurity in USA. I've heard that my bachelor's GPA will be taken as my reference GPA rather than my master's GPA. Where can I verify this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graduate admissions in the US will look at all of your GPAs from every program you've attended and consider the whole picture. There is no one "reference GPA" and no explicit formula for admissions for the majority of programs in the US.

Comment: I thought it was automated like filtering resumes.

Comment: @barnyard9 There is sometimes a specified lower limit to prevent applicants from wasting their time applying to programs that definitely won't be accepted. If you exceed that limit with one of your degrees but not the other you can *ask* the program, but to be blunt if you're in that category your chances of admission are likely very low.

Comment: Also keep in mind that masters programs in the US will expect you to pay for the tuition yourself; there's almost no funding available for masters students.

Comment: I'm talking about public universities.

Comment: @barnyard9 Yes, you pay tuition at US public universities. Especially international students.

Comment: Yeah studying isn't free, you don't need to shout about that.

Comment: Okay; I mention it because people familiar with other systems may be surprised how much students are expected to pay in the US.

Comment: That's good. Even I had delusions that you can study with scholarships in the USA in my earlier life. While that might be true for exceptional students to some extent, it's not the norm. You're doing good by letting people prepared for the worst.